# Facebook graph api feed and home give old data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I using facebook graph api explorer for feed and home data,it always gives old result.
Generally me/home gives recent friends activity which show as like as when facebook.com open and feed gives if someone tag me,or comment my status releted to me.but when I compare with my feed wall with data given by grap api me/feed or me/home its show that graph api response is not updated. I can't use real time update its only because real time update does not support native desktop application.

so is there any other way to get recent update of recent activites except me/home and me/feed method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using real time update. The fact that it doesn't support native desktop application isn't a real problem. It just means that you have to do some alternations in your application.

I don't know what OS you are using or what programming language you are using, but I think it's rather safe to say that your toolbox when it comes to your technologies can support calls to a web server or a web service.

Then you should use the web server or web service to implement the real time update specifications given by Facebook.

Alternative, you call poll Facebook API on a regular basis but I would not recommend it.

Use real time update and check your web server for new messages. This solution is working quite good. I have received updates from Facebook within 10 seconds after they have been posted.

If you don't want to poll your web server, try to implement it using web sockets (HTML5), perhaps in combination with node.js.